# Poweredge R330 Fan Noise

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell

I have just purchased and installed a Dell Poweredge R330 in my office and it's a little noisy for my liking.
I have spent the day searching and tried lots of different things but none seem to make a difference. I cannot get my fans to go below 6000rpm. For example: System Board Fan2A 30% 6240 RPM

I'm currently on the "minimum power" thermal profile with the fan offset set to off. I have tried the different settings in the BIOS and all seem the same that is idles at 5800-6200rpm. I don't seem why it needs to be this high. The CPU seems solid at 34c. It just seems over the top to me.

Can anyone suggest how to quieten this down? Other than that it's a lovely server!

Comment: Ask them, they have support: https://www.dell.com/support/

Comment: Why do you buy a server which is clearly meant to go in a data center (where noise is less of a concern) and put it on your desk? If you want a silent server to put on your desk, buy a server which has been made for that purpose.

Comment: It's not on my desk, It's in my large business office which contains 3 people. It's running a large manufacturing workshop. It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: No, it's not the right tool. You'll get the same class of hardware/performance in a lot more silent  variant as a workstation if it really does need to get in your office.  Everything about a rack server is usually designed with the idea in mind that noise doesn't matter because it goes into a data center.

Comment: @M4TVW have you seen this? https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/Dell-PowerEdge-fan-speed-change-fanspeed-offset/td-p/5187784

Comment: "It's the right tool for the job." Sure, if you ignore the noise.

Comment: Mods why is this off topic? This is a legitimate issue with the 13G Dell servers. I've encountered this while provisioning dozens of them. This can be fixed with an ipmitool command `ipmitool -I lanplus -H ipaddress of idrac -U username -P password raw 0x30 0xCE 0x00 0x09 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x02 0x02 0x02 0x00 0x00` https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln285596/drac-how-to-set-fan-speed-offset-values-in-idrac7-without-reboot?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Check the DRAC LCD, if for any reason it’s amber, like for a missing secondary power supply not plugged it, the fan will make more noise.

If the LCD is green, then no, a server is make to have optimal air flow for having it  work the maximum time possible, as such it’s not tweakable, or if you do you will possibly void the warrenty. Planning to install it in a closed room maybe with an A/C is the next step.

On rare case an update to the BIOS or management card can help, I seen some situation where it can be a bug in the firmware, but it was more in IBM server than Dell.